What real world use cases are there for the http-equiv attribute?
I'm taking a deep dive into html elements for the sake of knowledge and I've come across the http-equiv attribute which can be applied to the <meta> tag, and I'm just baffled by it. I want to know what real world uses there are for this attribute and why it might be important (if at all) in modern web development.
X-UA-Compatible
According to the accepted answer on this post, X-UA-Compatible is just for Internet Explorer compatibility and is essentially redundant in modern website. This makes complete sense.
content-security-policy
What I get from this MDN documentation is that the CSP just allows you to set permissions by setting property values such as img-src https://*; which would allow images to come from any source provided it is HTTPS encrypted. My guess is that this would apply to, for example: a blogging website that allows you to embed images but doesn't want to interact with unsecure domains.
Is this still something that it used in the modern day? Or is there a better/easier way of doing this now?
content-type
This post states that the use of <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> is just the old, outdated way of writing <meta charset="utf-8"> which makes sense to me, but I don't see why one would ever have needed to specify that the content is text and html in a html document.
Why was it written like this (specifying the input type) before it was simplified to just using a charset attribute?
default-style
This one seems self explanatory enough and I assume you could use this to automatically set the theme for a website using stored user preferences (i.e. the user selects dark-mode, that preference is stored as a variables, and that variable is used to determine the default-style when that user opens the website in future.
refresh
This one is self explanatory in what it does and further reading revealed that a URL can be provided to redirect users to, but what real world purpose would this be useful for?

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#attr-meta-http-equiv

@Rob This link provides no further context that answers my question(s) besides revealing that refresh could be used to make a slideshow. My post is asking for real world use cases, not syntax documentation.

How about content-security-policy?
